# Accesing the result of a mysql_result object

Tags: php, database, object, mysqli, resultset

I need to get the values of each cell in the table that I am querying in an associative array form. here is my query

```
$sqlStatemnt = "SELECT artist, track_name 
FROM Tracks where artist like 'bong' and track_name like 'bong' LIMIT 5";
```

and this how my php process it

```
$rs = $mySQL->query($sqlStatemnt);
print_r($rs);
```

the print_r shows me this

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 )
```

How would I access the table "track_name" and "artist" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
/* numeric array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM); //To get Indexed array
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);//To get associative array
```

Thanks

Comment: how come it is not printing when I do $print_r($row) on rows?

Comment: It should be print_r($row) not $print_r($row)

Answer (score 0):

There's a `fetch_assoc` related to mysqli result object. 
You can try something like this

```
artist = array();
track_name = array();
while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) !== FALSE) {
    $artist[] = $row['artist'];
    $track_name[] = $row['track_name'];
}
```

I hope this matches your implementation.

Find more about fetch_assoc here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: I am using mysqli. even thhough I tried mysqli fetch assoc it is giving me this error Fatal error: Call to undefined method MySQL::fetch_assoc()

Comment: The 'fetch_assoc' method is not static. You should use it using a mysqli object.